# xcode does not show "create ios distribution" option?

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, xcode8

I am trying to set up the xcode to publish my ionic app, I am following the ionic publishing guide (v1 for some reason they dont have it updated in version 2) the problem when I click create it does not show "ios distribution option".

[image]

how do i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They renamed the option from iOS Distribution to iOS App Store, so check the latter.